# Ограничение пользователей

Tags: права, debian, linux

Понадобилось очень остро ограничить пользователя. Но не знаю что и как, то есть что ограничивать, пользователю нужна возможность лишь редактировать текстовой файл и запускать программу в определенной директории. Более не куда ему доступ не нужен. Как можно такое устроить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. посмотрите в сторону chroot
2. посмотрите в сторону cgroups
3. вместо шелла дайте ему busybox ограниченный

Comment: Как наиболее просто и "хорошо" можно заставить пользователя сидеть в директории /home/user/ и более не куда его не пускать?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=chroot+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-aи первая же ссылка http://aboutubuntu.ru/content/chroot-vs-lshell-and-mysecureshell.html

Comment: Бывают в жизни огорчения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

я в таком случае вижу выход для себя в создании простого веб-интерфейса.

При формировании страницы текстовый файл [попадает](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) в [textarea](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea), а [submit](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/method) отправляет текст для [нового файла](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) и [вызывает запуск](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php) скрипта.